# Magento 1.9 standard RWD theme -- how do I display image labels on product view?

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, labels, view.phtml

I'm sure the answer is something really obvious and staring me in the face but it's doing my head in.

Stock standard Magento, in product view, where it shows the alternative images I need it to print/show the label of the image.

Preferably directly beneath the alternative image as per my (crappy) mock up.

Apart from CSS changes it's just the standard RWD theme if that helps at all.

I've tried the advice here: 
http://www.magentosolved.com/display-primary-image-label/

but it's not quite specific enough for me....
[image]

[image]

Comment: not worried about any CSS styling or anything, if I can just get the text on the page that would be fantastic

Answer (score 0):

Realised I was over-complicating it and just went with Swatches.

Cheers